# Whitespace parse error in haskell main block

Tags: haskell, whitespace, program-entry-point

Haskell appears to be extremely picky about whitespace in my main function.

The following compiles nicely

```
module Main where
import System.Environment

main :: IO()
main = do args <- getArgs
          putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ args !! 0)
```

But the following two programs give me a parse error

```
module Main where
import System.Environment

main :: IO()
main = do args <- getArgs
           putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ args !! 0)
```

and

```
module Main where
import System.Environment

main :: IO()
main = do args <- getArgs
         putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ args !! 0)
```

It would seem that `printStrLn` *must* line up with `args` or haskell throws a fit. This seems unnecessary. Why is haskell doing this?

Comment: Are you indenting with tabs, spaces or a mixture?  Haskell sometimes doesn't like mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: I am only using spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to [Mephy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23692683), while Haskell, written in usual Haskell style, *does* care about indentation (called ‘layout’ in the specification), you can write your code in a style such that indentation is ignored:

```
module Main where {
    import System.Environment;

    main :: IO ();
    main = do {
        args <- getArgs;
        putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ args !! 0)
    }
}
```

You don’t usually see this style being used for a whole module. Occasionally you’ll see it being used for a single short `do` or `let` block or something (you can mix both styles), but most people rely on layout.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell does indeed cares about indentation, just like Python. When using the `do` construct, you must have all your actions in the same column. Note you also need to use spaces, not tabs, as '\t' will usually get ignored.

Comment: Tabs are not ignored, but the language standard specifies that tab stops are at 8 spaces

Comment: But this is a single indented line. Why does Haskell care how far the indentation is?

Comment: Its not a single line, but two: `args <- getArgs` and `putStrLn ...`. Both must be at the same column.